# nginx as reverse proxy for multiple apps

Tags: nginx, docker

I want to use nginx as a reverse proxy for multiple apps (in docker). They exist in separate directories in the nginx container: `/var/www/app1`, `/var/www/app2`, etc.

My `default.conf`:

```
resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=15s;

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com example.com;
  set $upstream phpmyadmin:9000;

  location ^~ /phpmyadmin {
   #alias /var/www/html/;                 # <----- this works
    alias /var/www/phpmyadmin/;
    index index.php;
    location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files     $uri = 404;
      fastcgi_pass  $upstream;
      include       fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
  }

}
```

If I mount the docker app (phpmyadmin) in `/var/www/html/` then the above nginx config works.

But what I really want is to mount it in `/var/www/phpmyadmin/`. When I do that I get errors:

> FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream

Comment: Have you tried `root /var/www;` instead of `alias /var/www/phpmyadmin/;`?

Comment: @RichardSmith Yeah thought of that, doesn't make a difference unfortunately (same error). So you believe it looks ok? If so then it must be a problem with the app itself (phpmyadmin) or the docker network... which would be weird because it works when I use `/var/www/html/` as the mount point.

Comment: @RichardSmith Found the problem... the incorrect uri was being used because of the prefix. Added answer below. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strip prefix from `$fastcgi_script_name`:

```
fastcgi_split_path_info ^\/phpmyadmin\/(.+\.php)(.*)$;
```

Then use it:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $fastcgi_script_name;
```